# Modular PSU PCI-E Cable Wiring

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply

I have an EVGA SuperNOVA GS 850.

While modifying the modular PCI-E/VGA cable to remove the second 6+2 connector I noticed that the pin out on the second connector is different to the first.

This confuses me! I assumed that the two 6+2 connectors would be copies of each other.

My plan was to create two cables one with an 8 pin connector and one with a  6 pin connector. Does it matter which pinout I use? One of each?

The image below shows the three connectors, the numbers in the bottom two connectors indicate which pin on the first they are connected to.

[image: pinout of pci-e/vga cable]

Answer (score 0):

You probably confused the VGA cable with the EPS one (the one who should be connected to your MB).
They're supposed to be different connectors in order to prevent the users connect the VGA rail to the MB and vice versa.
You could confirm that by looking at your [cables connectors shape](http://www.jonnyguru.com/modules/NDReviews/images/EVGA850GS/DSC_7237.jpg), as you can see, the MB connector (the one that is in the upper right corner) is shaped differently from the rest of the VGA's connectors.